# How to overwrite customer registration REST API in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

Any once please help me out for overwrite the REST api in magento 2.3 please describe with example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a webapi.xml file under etc folder within your custom module

**webapi.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
  <route url="/V1/customers" method="POST">
    <service class="VendorName\ModuleName\Api\AccountManagementInterface" method="createAccount"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
  </route>
</routes>
```

You need to define interfaces same as AccountManagementInterface of customer module. I hope it will work. Let me know if you need further help :)

Comment: Thanks For your Reply, It's show dependency error like "Class ABC\\Customer\\Model\\EmailNotificationInterface does not exist" & once i copy that file from core to my module it's work so this is a right way to do that?

Comment: what do you want to achieve by overriding endpoint?

Comment: I have created some custom attribute so i would like to get in response that's why i need to overwrite the above API. Can you please help me to solve this "EmailNotificationInterface does not exist" error?

Answer (score 1):

If you want just add some custom data to response, there is no reason to do some overrides. You can archive this with use of *extension attributes* [there](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/292263/extension-attribute-in-quote-item/292276#292276) I provided an example (about quote item, but for Customer idea should be the same). If you don't know about *extension attributes* [there](https://store.fooman.co.nz/blog/an-introduction-to-extension-attributes.html) a good starting point.