# How to create customer without firstname and lastname in Magento 2 Api

Tags: magento2, api, customer-registration

I am using magento 2.3.2 version.

I need to remove the Firstname and Lastname fields in the new customer creation/ registration API. I referred [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/267813/how-to-overwrite-customer-registration-rest-api-in-magento-2-3)

Comment: It's mandatory to add firstname and lastname while creating customer. The one way which you can use for this is:- create a hidden field for firstname and lastname and add some static value in it.. like Guest User or Test User

Answer (score 2):

**Firstname and Lastname** are mandatory fields for the customer, So you have to set some value for these fields during registration, at least some dump value like (`-`), etc..

So,if you **DO NOT** want to provide these two fields value during  hitting the API point `/V1/customers` then you have to work on `Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface`[,**Create a plugin**](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)  on `createAccount()` and set some dump value to **Firstname and Lastname** to this field.

**Plugin Class**

```
<?php
namespace StackExchange\Magento\Plugin;

use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;

class AccountManagementPlugin 
{
    public function beforeCreateAccount(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface $subject,
        CustomerInterface $customer,
        $password = null,
        $redirectUrl = ''
    ){
        // Set dump value to - to firstName and last Name
        if($customer->getFirstname() == null){
            $customer->setFirstname('-');
        }
        if($customer->getLastname() == null){
            $customer->setLastname('-');
        }       
        return [$customer,$password,$redirectUrl];
    }
}
```