# How to read a value from `quote_address` table

Tags: magento2.4, quote

I have created a custom column in `quote_address` table and now trying to copy the value from `quote_address` to `sales_customer_address` table by trying to observe the event `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before`

While loading the quote, using `$quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();` I am not able to get the value of my custom field stored in `quote_address` table.

Also, I tried using `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address` but can't get the value of my custom field.

Can someone let me know how can I get the value of custom field from `quote_address` table?

Comment: Magento Extension attributes can help.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/292263/extension-attribute-in-quote-item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the address if you already have the object of quote then you can try these,

```
$quote->getBillingAddress()->getCustomField()
$quote->getShippingAddress()->getCustomField()
```

but for this to work also hope you are saving the data correctly in the quote_address table, by using extension_attributes, if not let us know, will update the answer